# Center Aligned Button's Text on Left

Tags: android, button, text-align

Even though I made gravity center text is still on left. I assume there must be a method to change text align 
(I have tried android:textAlignment="center" too)

I've included screenshot below but dont have enough reputation to make show it.

```
<!-- language: lang-xml-->    
<Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="50"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Button" />
```

also tried to make it match_parent still the same problem.

EDIT for whole XML

```
<!-- language: lang-xml-->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etCommands"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Type a Command"
        android:password="true" >
    </EditText>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="100" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Button" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvResults"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="invalid" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/11xSf.png)

Comment: yes I know it means I tried.

Comment: Just remove `android:gravity="center"`

Comment: I did add it to prevent any comments "just add android:gravitity:center" without this I am having same issue

Comment: can you plz post the total xml

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I had this problem too. Just restart your IDE.

Comment: Restarting IDE works for me. Hope there is a refresh or re-render button in Eclipse for this

Answer (score 0):

Adding android:layout_gravity="center" to the layout for the button and have the width wrap_content should fix it.

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry, I just realized you were talking about the text and not the actual button. I should read more carefully. Will look a little more

Comment: You want the text "Button" to be centered? Because it looks like it is to me on your screenshot and when I copy your code and run it

Comment: weird... I just copied my code to my another computer it worked well there... something must be wrong with ide.

Comment: Yes, I see. Its completely centered when I do it so I don't know why it isn't for you. You could add android:paddingRight="xdp" where x= probably 20 or 30 dp