# Center text in TextView and Button

Tags: android, layout, textview

I am trying to center the text in my `TextView` and `Button`. I currently have the following code:

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"        
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="#000000" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.15"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/CouponFinder"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textColor="#FF0000"
            android:typeface="monospace" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/couponImage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.7"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:src="@drawable/coupon" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.15"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:text="@string/continueButton"
            android:textSize="30sp" 
            android:gravity="center"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

However, the text in the `Button` and `TextView` are to the right and hence some of the text is off the screen... I am also getting the following warning for my `LinearLayout`:

`This LinearLayout layout or its RelativeLayout parent is possibly useless`

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Realized that some of the suggestions below do in fact work... When I test it on my phone, the output is correct. The Graphical Layout in Eclipse for some reason however doesn't display this correctly. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
        android:background="#000000" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.15"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="CouponFinder"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textColor="#FF0000"
            android:typeface="monospace" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/couponImage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.7"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:src="@drawable/icon" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.15"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:text="continueButton"
            android:textSize="30sp" 
            android:gravity="center"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Hi Tamilan, using this code I get an output identical to what I originally had =/ http://i.imgur.com/WsKKhZZ.png

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
[<TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="0.15"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:hint="asdasasdasdd"
                android:text="adasdasdasd"
                android:textAlignment="gravity"
                android:textColor="#FFffff"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:typeface="monospace" />]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"

tools:context=".MainActivity" >

      <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/couponImage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.7"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/coupon" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="continueButton"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="CouponFinder"
        android:textColor="#FF0000"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:typeface="monospace" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You should make the `RelativeLayout` a `LinearLayout`, and get rid of the internal `LinearLayout`, unless you plan to make modifications and add more things inside the `RelativeLayout` and outside of the `LinearLayout`.
2. Try setting the `layout-gravity` on the items instead of `gravity`.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks Gil, however I'm still not getting the correct alignment. This is what it currently looks like after I made your suggested changes. http://i.imgur.com/uvbSFjd.png

Answer (score 0):

The warning is because you are using only one `LinearLayout` as the Child View for `RelativeLayout`.So remove your `RelativeLayout`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"        
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#000000" >

     <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.15"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/CouponFinder"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:textColor="#FF0000"
    android:typeface="monospace" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/couponImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.7"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="@string/CouponFinder" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.15"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
         android:text="@string/continueButton"
        android:textSize="30sp" 
        android:gravity="center"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Try the above data.I got this by the above data

[image]

Comment: Thanks Manishika, but this aligned the the text in the text view to the top-left hand corner and did not change the button text...

Comment: How exactly you want your layout to look like.Can you post a picture?

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#000000"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.15"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="CouponFinder"
    android:textColor="#FF0000"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:typeface="monospace" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/couponImage"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.7"
    android:src="@drawable/icon" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.15"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="continueButton"
    android:textSize="30sp" />

  </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Hi tsp, using this code I get an output identical to what I originally had =/ i.imgur.com/WsKKhZZ.png

Answer (score 0):

What you've done is correct, but to see the changes, you just need to restart your IDE. I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15111841/3842936).